# Safe way to auto reply to all emails

Tags: email, exchange, email-server, auto-reply

The sales team wants to automatically send out a reply to all senders who contact their group mailbox. Something saying "Hi, thanks for contacting us, we will get back to you in 48 hours."

After some searching, I found I could:

- Create an Out of Office response - drawback: only once per sender
- Create a server-side rule to respond to all e-mails - drawback: infinite mail loops, replies to spammers as well, risk of getting on blocklists
- Transport rule - drawback: same as above; also, this is not what transport rules are for, so it would rustle my jimmies.

These ([1](https://serverfault.com/questions/646155/new-inboxrule-to-autoreply-or-always-autoreply), [2](https://serverfault.com/questions/125151/exchange-out-of-office-sending-an-ooo-reply-for-every-email)) threads here didn't really have a solution either.

Any ideas?

Maybe a way to have OoO replies fire every day? Have it automatically renew itself every day.

Any tricky way to get out of loops? Maybe maximize emails sent per hour from the address?

Using Office 365, Exchange Online.

Comment: solution one would be the one to go. "Only once per sender" is not true, you can define the amount as well as the time period for the amount of responses. That depends on your mail filter system. Honestly I am not versed enough on Exchange to know that. Sieve can do this.

Comment: .. but you're right in a way that this should be more configurable, downvote changed to upvote ;-)

Comment: Thanks. :) I'll keep looking into my options here, if I come across a viable solution, I'll post back.

Comment: @roothahn you said "you can define the amount as well as the time period for the amount of responses". I can't find this for the life of me. There is no such option in Outlook, and i didn't find anything like this in Exchange. Google failed me too. Can you give me a clue please?

Comment: I said Sieve can do this (vacation plugin, :days / :seconds), and I said it depends on your filter system. I hardly believe that Exchange is not able to do this too, since it costs a shitload of money.

Comment: @roothahn Oh, thanks. :) I'll look into using Sieve on Exchange online. All evidence suggests Exchange lacks this functionality be default. Sorry for being dumb, I need to read up on Sieve. (Did I mention that I was a programmer, not a sys admin? Somehow Exchange management got dumped on me.) Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: yep, that's the downside of hosted services. "One cannot simply" add functionality ;-)